# Y alignment constraint not working properly

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

I've come across a weird problem in interface builder.Here's a screenshot of what I've done.

[image]

In above screenshot dark grey area is scroll view. In that, I have put Company label 10 units below (i.e. 10 `constant` in constraint). Then Label 1 is 10 units below Company Label. Then line separator is 10 units below Label 1 and so on....

It is working perfectly till Label 3. but as I'm put separator-3 10 units below something weird happens. Company Name label and Label 1 shifts downwards (as shown in screenshot 2 below).

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For the last separator, when you add the constraints, in the top selector do you select label3 as the reference point?

Comment: @Sana Yes. Every element is referenced to its preceding element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what constraints you are adding, but the best way to add such data is to use a UITableView instead of using a UIScrollView and adding so many objects to it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,But UITableView is better for displaying uniform data. Here next fields will me more than just labels.

Comment: Yeah,that will work. I just want to know what's the problem with this scenario.

Comment: may be label3 was dependent on other label, that might create an error. I can't be sure unless i see the code.